# jQuery: .append or .appendTo PHP to an element within an HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to learn techniques for reducing the amount of code I write. I have a rather long form which I populate using PHP. I am wondering if it's possible to append PHP within HTML tags.

For example, rather than writing this:

```
<div id="title">Referrals</div>
        <input type="hidden" name="REFERRALS" value="n"/>
        <input id="wref" type="radio" name="REFERRALS" value='w' <?php echo ($REFERRALS == 'w') ? "checked='checked'" : "" ; ?> />        
            <label for="wref"></label>
        <input id="pref" type="radio" name="REFERRALS" value='p' <?php echo ($REFERRALS == 'p') ? "checked='checked'" : "" ; ?> /> 
            <label for="pref"></label>  
        <input id="cref" type="radio" name="REFERRALS" value='c' <?php echo ($REFERRALS == 'c') ? "checked='checked'" : "" ; ?> /> 
            <label for="cref"></label>
        <hr noshade></hr> 

 <div id="title">Laundry</div>
        <input type="hidden" name="LAUNDRY" value="n"/>
        <input id="wlaundry" type="radio" name="LAUNDRY" value='w' <?php echo ($LAUNDRY == 'w') ? "checked='checked'" : "" ; ?> />        
            <label for="wlaundry"></label>
        <input id="plaundry" type="radio" name="LAUNDRY" value='p' <?php echo ($LAUNDRY == 'p') ? "checked='checked'" : "" ; ?> /> 
            <label for="plaundry"></label>  
        <input id="claundry" type="radio" name="LAUNDRY" value='c' <?php echo ($LAUNDRY == 'c') ? "checked='checked'" : "" ; ?> /> 
            <label for="claundry"></label>
        <hr noshade></hr>           

 <div id="title">Shower</div>
        <input type="hidden" name="SHOWER" value="n"/>
        <input id="wshower" type="radio" name="SHOWER" value='w' <?php echo ($SHOWER == 'w') ? "checked='checked'" : "" ; ?> />       
            <label for="wshower"></label>
        <input id="pshower" type="radio" name="SHOWER" value='p' <?php echo ($SHOWER == 'p') ? "checked='checked'" : "" ; ?> /> 
            <label for="pshower"></label>   
        <input id="cshower" type="radio" name="SHOWER" value='c' <?php echo ($SHOWER == 'c') ? "checked='checked'" : "" ; ?> /> 
            <label for="cshower"></label>
        <hr noshade></hr>
```

I would like to use a jQuery statement such as...

```
variableName = $("input[name*='value']").val();
$('input[value^=']').append(<?php echo (variableName == 'c') ? "checked='checked'" : "" ; ?>);
```

to append the PHP within every relevant HTML tag.

However, I have no idea whether this is possible and have yet to find any solutions within the jQuery api.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do - Jquery code runs in your browser, after you have assembled the webpage server-side with PHP. Or are you maybe writing some kind of web-authoring plugin on the client side?

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: This is a technique designed strictly for eliminating key strokes. Essentially, on page load I want every input to have the php with correct variable added within the input tags. There is other code that checks to see if the PHP variables are set, etc. I for future projects I want to know if there is a way, with the proper planning, I could prevent myself from having to copy and paste all the PHP, changing each variable name.

Comment: I also now see that I need to create three variables and specify whether I am appending to w, p, or c. I should have considered that before posting.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use JavaScript (jQuery being a JavaScript library) to interact with PHP in this way.

PHP is parsed on the server and the resultant HTML is sent to your browser to be rendered.

You *can* interact with the HTML your browser receives using JavaScript (and/or jQuery), but then lose the ability to persist data, for example following a form submission, without involving a server or some kind of client-side storage.

Comment: So, essentially if I appended the PHP on page load it wouldn't receive information from the server. It would "disrupt" the flow of information so-to-speak?